# Reduce mutex overhead in multi-threading voxel algorithms

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm, mutex, voxel

I'm currently implementing a multi-threaded voxel game engine. As I'm going with multithreading I quickly run into performance bottleneck with mutexes.

For clarifying my problem let's take a 2D case:

```
+-+-+-+
|A|B|C|
+-+-+-+
|D|E|F|
+-+-+-+
|G|H|I|
+-+-+-+
```

All these cells are voxel chunks (16x16 voxels).

I do all voxel algorithms in a chunk basis using multiple threads. I have a job queue consisting of chunks to be worked on, and each worker thread just continuously picks chunks from the queue and works on it.

Now imagine one thread needs to do some lighting calculations in chunk E. Because there may be a light source in a corner of E which will propagate to neighbouring chunks, it has to lock all nine neighbouring chunks around to avoid potential data race, using mutexes.

However as I've experimented, the performance overhead with mutexes is not good. Currently I'm using a simple `for` loop to add the jobs. So when the game is run the initial job queue would become something like:

```
A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, ...
```

This is really bad, as the first job A will locks A, B, D, E and makes all following eight jobs waiting for the mutexes, killing performance.

Currently the only mitigation I can think of is to try to add jobs in a disperse way, hoping we can avoid most stalls. But I do not like this approach as it looks more like a workaround and not very flexible if the locking pattern changes.

I have also thought of using "asynchronous mutexes". But I'm not very sure how to do it.

EDIT:
Just to clarify, the lighting jobs are added in runtime and not in a fixed order. For example, imagine the player moves out of currently processed chunks, then only the outside chunks should be added to the queue, which may be in an irregular boundary.

So I think using a decent scheduler solely is not sufficient to solve this issue.

Comment: Assuming your voxel chunks are not too big would it be possible to copy affected chunks, process them and merge results at the end? eg. Thread 1 pulls chunk A, sees it needs to perform lighting on chunks C and F. It then copies C and F and proceeds to work on them. Thread 2 pulls chunk B and sees also needs to work on C. It also copies C and works on it. Once all chunks are processed the main thread gets the results from each thread and performs additive blending to get the final light map.

Comment: @Wes Clever idea. But most voxel algorithms I'm using (including lighting) should have a performance close at O(N) level (N is chunk size). The additional step of visiting all chunks in the main thread just renders multi-threading useless.

Comment: Are the whole code blocks mutually exclusive? That is, if you cannot do anything for `B` while `A` is running, just move `B` to the back of the queue and fetch the next item. Of course, this might not work if you already did some work for `B`. You don't want to rollback work, I guess.

Comment: @Heuster: It is mutually exclusive. Or at least I have to do additional blending steps as @Wes said. Your approach should work in theory. But how to store and fetch the information of who is working on which chunks? In the above figure I'm locking mutexes sequentially (e.g. For `E`, locking `A`, `B`, `C`, ..., `I`, one-by-one). Because we cannot atomically lock all nine mutexes at once and this scheme can avoid dead-locks. If it's without mutexes, or maybe using mutex.tryLock(), how to avoid deadlocks (and potentially livelocks)?

Comment: OK, how often does such a collision happen?  I understand that such events must not happen, but if they are relatively infrequent, it should be possible to design a better anti-collison strategy that avoids nine mutex-locks in the non-collision case but requires more action when a colision is actualy detected.  That would improve performace overall.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long to fit in the comments sections.

How about using an atomic bool to see if a chunk is currently being processed? This way you will get higher thread utilization instead of threads waiting to do processing. Also if you start each thread at equally dispersed points you will get fewer collisions. This algorithm then just resolves the issue when threads need to work on the same chunks.

1. Thread 1 gets chunk A (affects chunks B and C) and sets A's processing flag.
2. Thread 2 at the same time gets chunk B and sets B's processing flag.
3. Thread 1 finishes chunk A and resets A's flag and checks if chunk B is available.
4. Thread 2 is busy with B so thread 1 leaves B unprocessed for now moves onto C and sets C's flag.
5. Thread 2 finishes with B resets B's flag.
6. Thread 1 finishes C and resets C's flag and then moves to B. B already has thread 2's results so thread 1 does a final pass on B and is done.

Comment: The issue is my current lighting algorithm needs all 9 chunks to be available and processes all of them at once. It cannot do in a partial and resumable way. Not only the lighting algorithm but alao some procedural generation algorithms I'm using needs this behaviour (need all neighbouring chunks to work). Using this approach will make coding much harder.

Answer (score 0):

what about sheduling with some offset between threads like this:

[image: offset-ed sheduling]

- different colors means different worker thread
- image represents single row in your map
- more in text bellow

You have 4 or 8 neigbours and for example 4 worker threads

- for clarity cell 0102 means row=01 column - 02 (all counted from 0)

  ```
  thread 0000 00001 0002 0003
  -------------------------
         cell cell cell cell
  -------------------------
         0000 0003 0006 0009
         0001 0004 0007 0010
         0002 0005 0008 0011

         0012 0015 0018 0021
         0013 0016 0019 0022
         0014 0017 0020 0023

         0024 0027 0030 0033
         0025 0028 0030 0034
         0026 0029 0030 0035

         ... till end of row

         0100 0103 0106 0109
         0101 0104 0107 0110
         0102 0105 0108 0111

         0112 0115 0118 0121
         0113 0116 0119 0122
         0114 0117 0120 0123

         0124 0127 0130 0133
         0125 0128 0130 0134
         0126 0129 0130 0135

         ... till end of row
         ... till end map
  ```
- the bigger the gap between threads the better
- 2 spaces is minimum
- when hitting the end of row threads should wait to be completed all before sheduling next row
- also you can completely avoid conflicts when you shedule the gap edge first and then the rest

  - instead of 0000,0001,0002 would be 0002,0000,0001

**This approach can create data propagation artifacts !!!**

- because data is not continuosly propagated between neighbours
- so some grid like artifacts can appear ...